# pyCharm on w7 64_bit

Tags: python, path, pycharm, jvm, windows-7-x64

**first one:
----------**
the procedure entry point ucrtbase.terminate could not be loacated the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll when open pycharm

**next one:
---------**
Failed to load JVM DLL C:\program files\JetBrains\PyCharm2019.1.3\jre64\bin\server\jvm.dll
if you already have a 64-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variables in Environment Variables

Comment: Windows 7 is unsupported [both by Microsoft and by Jet-brain) (and obsolete). If you have a valid license for windows 7 you may still be able to upgrade (and BTW you can do also without licenses, just you get a limited version, which may be good). Our sister site superuser.com has already the answers for all of this. As alternative you may install Linux (there are free distributions, maybe just with external USB drives/sticks). Both methods give you modern python/pycharm and also supported browsers (to read documentation).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows

The system requirements on their website state, that you need Windows 8 or 10.

I guess there is simply no support for Windows 7.